# multiple decrease increase app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, development-environment

I have following this tutorial and got it to work:
http://www.thetutorialblog.com/cocoa-objective-c/creating-a-basic-ipad-application/

But now I need multiple of that function in my app. I know I can write code for each other but that gonna take me so long time. Do anyone know how I can do this easier?

I want it like this:

```
- 0 +    - 0 +
- 0 +    - 0 +
- 0 +    - 0 +
- 0 +    - 0 +
- 0 +    - 0 +
- 0 +    - 0 +
- 0 +    - 0 +
- 0 +    - 0 +
```

But much more...

Comment: Why do you need multiple functions? You just need multiple UI elements linked to the same function.

Comment: whats that function? I tried to linked buttons to the functions in that tutorial but it doesn't work. every 0 need to work for it self

Answer (score 0):

Open up `TutorialViewController.xib`. from the library drag Multiple labels and multiple buttons.
Apply this two steps for all buttons and labels
1. Control + click the File's Owner object and drag it to the label  then select currentNumber;  // for all labels
 2. Now go from the minus and plus button to the File's Owner object and select decrementNumber for the minus button and incrementNumber for the plus minus and plus buttons. // for all buttons

Comment: I have done this.. But it not working. Now all button is changing one label only.